# Convert a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, nsstring

My situation is explained in the code below.
I need to send via a socket NSString drawn from a TextBox

Thank you very much

```
NSString *string = fieldTesto.txt;
// I Find an istruction for insert s string in to the CFSocketSend
UInt8 message[] = "Hello world";
CFDataRef data = 
             CFDataCreate(NULL, message, sizeof(message));
CFSocketSendData(s, NULL, data, 0);
CFRelease(data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your string to `NSData` and then use the toll-free bridging to `CFData`.

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
...
CFSocketSendData(s, NULL, (CFDataRef)data, 0);
```

Comment: warning: passing argument 3 of 'CFSocketSendData' from incompatible pointer type

Comment: Just fixed it. You only need to cast it properly.